# How can I make an inset shadow span the whole page with absolute positioned elements in it?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page which has an inset box shadow on its body element. There are absolute and relative positioned divs on the page which can get big enough that a scrollbar appears to fully show them. The box shadow will then be cut off even at 100% or 100vh height. Is there a way to make the box shadow always span the whole page, even if a div makes it larger? Interestingly the background does continue below the normal viewport.

I have tried all the various shennanigans with height min-height on the html and body tag but to no avail.

Here is a dumbed down snippet that shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/6ay8rusf/1/

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#333;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}
.abs{
  left: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I hope to have the inset shadow span the whole page and not be cut off at 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
    body{
      margin: 0;
      background-color:#333;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      min-height: calc(100vh + 50px + 20px); /* this is, .abs height + .abs top: value + .abs margin-bottom: value */
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .abs{
      left: 50%;
      top: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 100vh;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
Test
<div class="abs"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there also an option if the position and height are dynamic? I know I could calculate this with a little js but I was wondering if there was a simple css solution I did not see. In my case the div houses results from an ajax request and hence the height is dynamic.